# How to reload page after bootstrap modal closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

```
$("#customerAdded").modal("show").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#customerAdded").modal("hide");
                }, 5000);
                location.reload();                  
            });
```

Ok, it works. But with **location.reload()**, despite I change the time,  the page is reloaded immediately. 
I would, after modal closed, that the page was reloaded according the time specified.

Comment: window.setTimeout is executing asynchronically. You should put location.reload() in the window.setTimeout method after $("#customerAdded").modal("hide");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just fire the location.reload() when you hide your modal:

```
$("#customerAdded")
.modal("show")
.on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $("#customerAdded").modal("hide");
        location.reload(); 
    }, 5000);                 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#customerAdded").modal("hide").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {        
        location.reload();                   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
$('#customerAdded').on('hidden', function () {
    location.reload();
})
```